# Webpack Module build failed isn't a valid CSS value

Tags: webpack, build, sass, jhipster, yarnpkg

We are having problem with webpack building modules from bootstrap.scss file for jhipster and angular2.

when we run the webpack build command for this config file we get this error :

```
ERROR in ./~/css-loader!./~/postcss-loader!./~/sass-loader/lib/loader.js!./src/main/webapp/content/scss/vendor.scss
Module build failed: 
  0: (
    ^
      (x: 0, y: 0) isn't a valid CSS value.
      in xxxxxx/src/main/webapp/content/scss/bootstrap.scss (line 146, column 6)
 @ ./src/main/webapp/content/scss/vendor.scss 4:14-194
 @ ./src/main/webapp/app/vendor.ts
 @ dll vendor
```

I have an idea that it is cause by the configuration file or some of the node_moudles versions we are using.

The npm version I am using 4.2.0 and the node version is 7.10.0

The way we run it is in this sequence:
yarn install
yarn vendor to run the webpack configuration file
yarn start

the error for the css is given when running the yarn vendor configuration file.

The webpack config file(webpack.vendor.js) we are using is like this from hipster version (executed by calling the webpack/webpack.vendor.js --progress --profile && webpack -p --config from the package.json file see below the webpack config file) :

---

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
    entry: {
        'vendor': [
            './src/main/webapp/app/vendor',
            '@angular/common',
            '@angular/compiler',
            '@angular/core',
            '@angular/forms',
            '@angular/http',
            '@angular/platform-browser',
            '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic',
            '@angular/router',
            '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap',
            'ngx-infinite-scroll',
            'jquery',
            'ng-jhipster',
            'ng2-webstorage',
            'ngx-cookie',
            'rxjs'
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
        modules: ['node_modules']
    },
    module: {
        exprContextCritical: false,
        rules: [
            {
                test: /(vendor\.scss|global\.scss)/,
                loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader', 'postcss-loader', 'sass-loader']
            },
            {
                test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg|woff2?|ttf|eot)$/i,
                loaders: ['file-loader?hash=sha512&digest=hex&name=content/[hash].[ext]']
            }
        ]
    },
    output: {
        filename: '[name].dll.js',
        path: path.resolve('./target/www'),
        library: '[name]'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.DllPlugin({
            name: '[name]',
            path: path.resolve('./target/www/[name].json')
        })
    ]
};
```

---

the package json file looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "xxxx",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "Description for xxx",
  "private": true,
  "cacheDirectories": [
    "node_modules"
  ],
 "dependencies": {
    "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.1",
    "@angular/common": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/core": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/http": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.3.6",
    "@angular/router": "^4.3.6",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^1.0.0-beta.3",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0-beta",
    "core-js": "^2.5.1",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "gsap": "^1.20.2",
    "jquery": "3.2.1",
    "ng-jhipster": "0.2.6",
    "ng2-webstorage": "1.8.0",
    "ng4-geoautocomplete": "0.0.9",
    "ngx-cookie": "1.0.0",
    "ngx-infinite-scroll": "0.4.1",
    "normalize-scss": "^7.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "^5.4.3",
    "swagger-ui": "^2.2.10",
    "tether": "^1.4.0",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.17"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "4.1.3",
    "@types/gsap": "^1.19.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.47",
    "@types/node": "7.0.22",
    "add-asset-html-webpack-plugin": "1.0.2",
    "angular2-template-loader": "0.6.2",
    "angular2-uuid": "^1.1.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "3.1.3",
    "browser-sync": "2.18.12",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "1.1.4",
    "codelyzer": "2.1.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "0.28.3",
    "del": "2.2.2",
    "event-stream": "3.3.4",
    "exports-loader": "0.6.4",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "2.1.0",
    "file-loader": "0.11.1",
    "generator-jhipster": "4.5.1",
    "gulp": "^3.9.1",
    "gulp-connect": "^5.0.0",
    "gulp-sass": "^3.1.0",
    "gulp-shell": "^0.6.3",
    "gulp-wait": "^0.0.2",
    "html-loader": "0.4.5",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "2.28.0",
    "jasmine-core": "2.6.2",
    "karma": "1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "2.1.1",
    "karma-coverage": "1.1.1",
    "karma-intl-shim": "1.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "1.1.0",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "1.2.0",
    "karma-notify-reporter": "1.0.1",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "1.0.4",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "0.6.0",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "2.0.3",
    "kss": "^3.0.0-beta.18",
    "lazypipe": "1.0.1",
    "lodash": "4.17.4",
    "map-stream": "0.0.7",
    "merge-jsons-webpack-plugin": "1.0.6",
    "node-sass": "4.5.3",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "2.1.14",
    "plop": "^1.8.1",
    "postcss-loader": "1.3.0",
    "proxy-middleware": "0.15.0",
    "rimraf": "2.6.1",
    "run-sequence": "1.2.2",
    "sass-loader": "5.0.1",
    "sourcemap-istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "0.2.0",
    "string-replace-webpack-plugin": "0.1.3",
    "style-loader": "0.16.1",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.5",
    "tslint": "4.5.1",
    "tslint-loader": "3.5.3",
    "typescript": "2.3.3",
    "web-app-manifest-loader": "0.1.1",
    "webpack": "2.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "2.4.5",
    "webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
    "webpack-notifier": "1.5.0",
    "webpack-visualizer-plugin": "0.1.11",
    "write-file-webpack-plugin": "3.4.2",
    "xml2js": "0.4.17",
    "yargs": "6.6.0"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=6.9.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "cleanup": "rimraf target/{aot,www}",
    "generate": "plop",
    "kss": "kss --config kss-config.json",
    "ngc": "ngc -p tsconfig-aot.json",
    "start": "yarn run webpack:dev",
    "vendor": "webpack --config webpack/webpack.vendor.js --progress --profile",
    "webpack:dev": "webpack-dev-server --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --progress --inline --hot --profile --port=9060",
    "webpack:build:vendor": "webpack --config webpack/webpack.vendor.js --progress --profile",
    "webpack:build:dev": "webpack --config webpack/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile",
    "webpack:build": "yarn run cleanup && yarn run webpack:build:vendor && yarn run webpack:build:dev",
    "webpack:prod": "yarn run cleanup && webpack -p --config webpack/webpack.vendor.js --progress --profile && webpack -p --config webpack/webpack.prod.js --progress --profile"
  }
}
```

---

It works on two of the other developers machine but on mine machine it keep giving this error. Hope someone can help

Comment: Most probably you have got **newer version of bootstrap** which is incompatible with the one other developers still have. Make sure that your version matches theirs.

Comment: see my answer at below

Answer (score 0):

Hi we found the error it is related with package.json where it has automatic version bump up. What we did was to go back in our git repository and found a package.json where it all works and merge, it with the newest package.json we have and remove all  ^ (so it does not have automatic version bump up). A mistake from us to have automatic version bump up in the first place.